# No hard disk seen while installing Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to my dell Optiplex 7070 system. I have disabled the secure boot option from the BIOS. While making the installation, I only see my USB `Device for boot loader installation:` field. I tried switching to legacy external devices mode, there I could find the hard disk and completely installed Ubuntu, after wiping the system.

However, when I restart the system, it shows

> Critical Error Message: No bootable devices found.

Comment: Sometimes you actually have to point the bios to the correct directory to ensure the machine finds the correct boot folder (example /boot/efi). In the bios, check the boot menu and see what it shows. If you see a boot option there for your drive, click on it to see the path it is looking at. If you could find a way to take a picture of it that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm running 18.04 and the correct path for me is ``/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/``. In that directory there is a BOOTx64.efi file. I needed to add that path to the boot option in order to get my system to see it for the first time on my Dell Precision 3620.